# Debugging Elastic Beanstalk Docker run failures?

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to EB and AWS, and my docker images build fine but fail to run on Elastic Beanstalk. My suspicion is that they are not connecting to the database correctly, however, I'm not getting anything useful when I run "eb logs" from the commandline. Here are the errors:

```
{
  "status": "FAILURE",
  "api_version": "1.0",
  "results": [
    {
      "status": "FAILURE",
      "msg": "(TRUNCATED)...rrun.aws.json: No such file or directory
        73927c49adff622a1a229d9369bdd80674d96d20f3eb99a9cdea786f4411a368
        Docker container quit unexpectedly after launch: Docker container quit unexpectedly on Wed May 20 17:15:02 UTC 2015:.
        Check snapshot logs for details.
        Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/04run.sh failed.
        For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI",
      "returncode": 1,
      "events": [
        {
          "msg": "Successfully pulled node:0.12.2-slim",
          "severity": "TRACE",
          "timestamp": 1432142064
        },
        {
          "msg": "Successfully built aws_beanstalk/staging-app",
          "severity": "TRACE",
          "timestamp": 1432142094
        },
        {
          "msg": "Docker container quit unexpectedly after launch: Docker container quit unexpectedly on Wed May 20 17:15:02 UTC 2015:. Check snapshot logs for details.",
          "severity": "ERROR",
          "timestamp": 1432142102
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "truncated": "true"
}
```

And after the build completes:

```
[2015-05-20T17:15:02.694Z] INFO  [8603]  - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/04run.sh] : Activity execution failed, because: cat: /var/app/current/Dockerrun.aws.json: No such file or directory
  cat: /var/app/current/Dockerrun.aws.json: No such file or directory
  73927c49adff622a1a229d9369bdd80674d96d20f3eb99a9cdea786f4411a368
  Docker container quit unexpectedly after launch: Docker container quit unexpectedly on Wed May 20 17:15:02 UTC 2015:. Check snapshot logs for details. (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: cat: /var/app/current/Dockerrun.aws.json: No such file or directory
  cat: /var/app/current/Dockerrun.aws.json: No such file or directory
  73927c49adff622a1a229d9369bdd80674d96d20f3eb99a9cdea786f4411a368
  Docker container quit unexpectedly after launch: Docker container quit unexpectedly on Wed May 20 17:15:02 UTC 2015:. Check snapshot logs for details. (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

The docker containers work locally, so what else can I do to figure out what's going wrong? I keep hearing about "snapshot logs" but where do I check these snapshot logs? Are they the output of what I'm already running "eb logs"?

Comment: do you have a Dockerrun.aws.json file in your project?

Comment: If you have a DockerFile you shouldn't need the Dockerrun.aws.json...

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to read the logs

Comment: If you can ssh onto the ec2 instance, then you can find the container id with `sudo docker ps -a`, then run `sudo docker logs <id>`.  There are also logs on the host at `/var/log/eb-docker/containers/`

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue for a day or two. I managed to see the logs by going AWS Console > Elastic Beanstalk > Environment > ${YOUR_APPLICATION_ENV}

On the left pane;

Log > Request Logs > Download > Open in any text editor.

`/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/`

Follow the path and you will see the what causing the error and can fix it.

Comment: Great and underrated answer. This helped me. Nicely done Eren

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have SSH access to the EC2 instance running your container, these are a few log files useful for debugging single container Docker instances in Beanstalk:

- */tmp/docker_build.log*
- */tmp/docker_pull.log*
- */tmp/docker_run.log*

In order to look at the error logs for the running process, first read the
*/tmp/docker_run.log* file. This file contains the Docker process id. Something like this:

`c6ae58e4ad77e926f6a8230237acf95771c6b5d80d48fb1bc20591f964fd690c`

The first few characters should match the process listed from the command `docker ps`. Use this value to find the corresponding log file in the following directory:

*/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/*

The format of the file name is *eb-**docker-ps-id**-stdouterr.log*

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when my containers were crashing because there was no traffic allowed between EBS and RDS. If you use any database try curling it. Also, you might want to try `sudo docker logs CONTAINER_ID` a try catching something useful. What might help also is trying to launch container manually from the instance. There's slight possibility something will come up.